# Which sn.exe should I use?

Tags: .net, assembly-signing

I want to experiment with signing my .Net assemblies with a strong name.  So I downloaded and installed the windows SDK, and then did `Dir /s sn.exe` in order to find the one directory where it was installed.

What I found was (scroll for sizes and dates):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\sn.exe                       03/18/2010  07:51 PM 95,552 bytes

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe       03/18/2010  07:51 PM 168,768 bytes

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\sn.exe   03/19/2010  06:16 AM 187,712 bytes

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\sn.exe                   03/19/2010  06:16 AM 102,208 bytes
```

So now I am confused as to which tool I should use to generate a .snk file (or even if the different version really matter)

FWIW I am running VS2010 on W7 64 bit, and looking at signing .Net 4 assemblies

Comment: I can't think of a reason it would make a difference.  Just don't bother, use the IDE.  Project + Properties, Signing tab.

Comment: @HansPassant OK .. I didn't see that I could create an .snk file there.  Which raises the question `why did I download the windows sdk?`.  Still I am confused by 4 different versions of sn.exe

Comment: I don't know of course, the SDK is already included with VS.  This otherwise caters to using the build tools from different build environments, mostly a C++ build detail.  You could tinker with the Visual Studio Command Prompt to find out more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK .. I think I see what I did here.  According to Hans' comment there should already have been a copy of sn.exe lying around on my computer.  In hindsight I believe that I missed it when I scanned for it before installing the SDK.

As a result I am guessing that the SDK loaded a newer version than what was supplied with VS2010.  Thus I found:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\ files             report version 3.5.30729.1  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\   report version 4.0.30319.1
```

Which looks like a .Net framework version number.  So I'll believe the NETFX versions are the ones to use.

As to x64 vs not-x64 .. that still confuses me as they are both installed into the (x86) directory.

Also as per Hans, I don't really need to use sn.exe anyway